# How to iterate a list row by row in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, foreach, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a `list<>` and I need to pass each row of the list to a stored procedure.

I am currently having a for each loop to count number of rows in the loop and iterate that many number of times. but it is iterating the first row only each time. Instead I want to go to next row each time.

I am building a web application using ASP.NET Core Razor pages and I do not want to use MVC architecture as I feel it is too complicated for me.

```
[BindProperty]
public OrderProduct OrderProduct { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveOrder()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    cart = SessionHelper.GetObjectFromJson<List<OrderProduct>>(HttpContext.Session, "ProductCart");
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
    {
        objProduct.AddProductsToOrder(OrderProduct);
    }
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Codexer's answers in the comments, this can be achieved by changing your loop to the following:

```cs
for (var i = 0; i <= cart.Count; i++)
{
    objProduct.AddProductsToOrder(cart[i]);
}
```

Notably, this changes:

- `< cart.Count` to `<= cart.Count`
- `objProduct.AddProductsToOrder(OrderProduct)` to `objProduct.AddProductsToOrder(cart[i])`

That said, a simple `foreach` would work much better, since you don't otherwise need the incrementor. This would look something like:

```cs
foreach (var product in cart) 
{ 
    objProduct.AddProductsToOrder(product); 
}
```